# Random multiplication table generator

Tags: php, random, multiplication

im creating an multiplication table system in PHP.

The input tho this system is an table number and the amount of questions. 
The table 1 is skipped so 2 to input table

At this point I just fill an array like this:

```
$nCount = $_POST['count'];
$nHighest = $_POST['table'];
$aSums = [];
$nCounter = 0;
while($nCount > 0){
    $cSumString = rand(2, $nHighest) . "*" . rand(1, 10);
    $aSums[$nCounter] = $cSumString
    $nCount--;
    $nCounter++;
}
```

I want to parse the questions in multiple ways:

```
3 * 5 = ... (normal)
... * 5 = 25 (first number to fill in)
8 * ... = 16 (second to fill in)
```

This needs to be randomised.

Example:

```
1 * 2 = ... 
6 * ... = 12 
... * 4 = 20
8 * 4 = ...
2 * ... = 6
```

The only thing I know that should be able to so this is a switch but I cant seem to get it to work propperly so if anyone can give me a push in the right direction i would appreciate it. Im not asking for instacode just some tips would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need help with your PHP code for your string generation with placeholder or generating a HTML table for your data or something else? Also is your code missing something after `$aSums[$nCounter] =` or is it really supposed to be `$aSums[$nCounter] = $nCount--;`?

Comment: @xander thx for pointing out what missed :S what I like help with is how do i generate the random ... spots. `... * ... = ...` These 3 possibilities. always 2 numbers and 1 blanc spot but random where the blancspot is. sorry if im unclear english isnt my first language :S

Comment: Give small example output, a bit confusingly worded question. Eg, if user chooses 2 & 3 hat might the random output be.

Comment: @H.Brendan If you want to keep it simple and only have those 3 versions you could use a simple [switch-case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), if it should be random just do `switch(rand(1, 3)) { case 1: ... case 2: ... case 3: ... }`. I'd also use a more mathematical variable like `x` instead of `...`, it looks better and makes it easier to replace it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$nCount = $_POST['count'];
$nHighest = $_POST['table'];
$aSums = [];
$leftOut = ['leftFactor', 'rightFactor', 'product'];

for ($i = 0; $i <= $nCount; $i++) {
  $leftOutRand = rand(0, count($leftOut) - 1);
  $factor = rand(1, $nHighest);
  $product = rand(0, $nHighest) * $factor;
  switch($leftOut[$leftOutRand]) {
    case 'leftFactor':
      $cSumString = '...' . ' * ' . $factor . ' = ' . $product;
      break;
    case 'rightFactor':
      $cSumString = $factor . ' * ' . '...' . ' = ' . $product;
      break;
    case 'product':
      $cSumString = rand(1, $nHighest) . ' * ' . rand(1, $nHighest) . ' = ' . '...';
      break;
  }
  $aSums[$i] = $cSumString;
}
```

example Output:

```
2 * ... = 4
... * 2 = 6
1 * 1 = ...
... * 2 = 6
3 * ... = 12
2 * ... = 2
2 * 4 = ...
4 * ... = 0
3 * 1 = ...
2 * 1 = ...
... * 4 = 16
1 * ... = 2
... * 2 = 2
1 * 4 = ...
3 * ... = 9
2 * 3 = ...
2 * ... = 6
... * 1 = 3
... * 4 = 4
1 * 1 = ...
... * 3 = 9
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot this works perfectly i was already trying this becouse xander told me in comments but this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$total = 4;
$table = 7;

$generate_pair = function() use ($table)
{
    $first = rand(1, 10);
    $last  = rand(2, $table);

    return [$first, $last];
};

$pairs = [];
while (count($pairs) < $total) {
    $pair = $generate_pair();
    if(!in_array($pair, $pairs))
        $pairs[] = $pair;
}

$questions = array_map(function ($v) {
    return sprintf('%d * %d', $v[0], $v[1]);
}, $pairs);

var_dump($questions);
```

Example output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "7 * 3"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "5 * 7"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "5 * 2"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "6 * 2"
}
```

Comment: Not quite what i asked but thanks anyway becouse this is better than how i did this part myself

Answer (score 0):

I would personally put it in an array and read it from there then its easier to get it trough an switch like Mark labenski mentioned and I would do it like this:

```
$questpertable = floor($questions / ($table-1));
$nTableCounter = 2; 
$array = [];
for ($nX = 0; $nX < ($table-1); $nX++){
  for ($nY = 0; $nY < $questpertable;){
      $left = rand(1, 10);
      $right  = $tablecounter;
      $answer = $left * $right;     
      $array[$nY] = array($left, $right, $answer );
      $Y++;                   
  }
  $tablecounter++;
}
```

The only thing that misses here is the residual value u will have to find something to fix this.

Comment: Thank you but I have used marks way to fill the array and to parse it also, wont your code overwrite the array positions everytime becouse u use nY as positioning? or am I wrong there?